# I am confused with drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi

Tags: android

i am attempting to get my android app to work on both phone type devices and tablets.  for the layouts i have layout-normal and layout-large and i place my xml files inside each and it seems to select the correct one for each device (layout-normal for phones and layout-large for tablets).

however the problem arises for the drawable folders.  i have drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi.  the tablet is taking its images from the drawable-mdpi, and the phone is taking its images from the drawable-hdpi.  from the reading i have been doing this seems to be backwards???  this seems to happen on both the emulator and real devices, could i be doing something wrong? am i mixing something up?

Comment: This is something strange,
I guess you are mistaking in putting the images in the folder..check once the high density image is in hdpi and medium in mdpi..

Comment: this solution is more appropriate i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209027/android-drawable-folders-clarification

Comment: the qualifiers for different pixel densities are explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clayton,

drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi is not related to the size of the screen itself, but to the resolution of the display.

It's probably easy to think in terms of the iPhone 3GS and 4 for this (bear with me please).  The 4 has retina display, hence a much higher resolution.  Using the same sprites you'd use with the 3GS would result in a blurry display.

Android phones are, if anything, much more diverse in terms of screen options.

If you want to be able to aim different layouts at different resolutions, please try putting the layouts into /layout-xlarge, /layout-large, etc...

You can find more here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

There are some changes that you can see for Android 3.2 and above:

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are
>   deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration
>   qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your
>   layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout 
>   requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in
>   layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout 
>   resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet 
>   Layouts for Android 3.2.

Answer (score 7):

ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi refer to pixel density, not screen size.

Comment: i guess i'm still confused though, so larger screen sizes are lower pixel density, or they really are not even related?

Comment: They're completely unrelated - at least in terms of predicting density from screen size or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer does not address a serious problem: if you have many drawables, you end up with an unnecessarily big apk file because of resource duplicating. The only solution for that is the resource alias option described here:
http://blog.evendanan.net/2011/03/Android-resources-and-device-fragmentation

**Edit**: I just beheld that OP didn't realize that most phones have hdpi density, while most tablets have mdpi density. At the same time the tablets mostly have higher resolution. Hence Android will use smaller pictures for higher resolution.
You can overcome this only by using vector images or using the methods described in the accepted answer and in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

drawable-hdpi - application use this drawable images when the device has high pixel density
drawable-mdpi - application use this drawable images when the device has medium pixel density
drawable-ldpi.-application use this drawable images when the device has low pixel density