# Android drawable folders clarification

Tags: android

I got images prepared for 7 inch and 10 inch tablets now i want to put them into corresponding drawable folder.I have searched some sources and got some information that both 7inch and 10inch tablets densities are **mdpi**. I can't put both images of different resolution on the same mdpi folder.Can anybody suggest me some idea on how to proceed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 inch tablets, comes into the largescreen category, and 10 inch tablets falls into xlarge-screen. so use following folders for both these:

1 `drawable-large`

2 `drawable-xlarge`

Answer (score 9):

Option #1: Use `res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/` for the 10-inch `-mdpi` tablet images and `res/drawable-large-mdpi/` for the 5-to-10-inch `-mdpi` tablet images.

Option #2: Do not have different icons based on screen size.

Comment: @CommonsWare you suggest this for only mdpi tablet in option #1,but what abt the tablets those are not mdpi?

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link for your solution.
Try to use

> drawable-large
>
> drawable-xlarge

Different category for support all resolution. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 1):

large and xlarge are deprecated from android 3.2
Use drawable-sw600dp-mdpi for 7" tabs and drawable-sw720dp-mdpi for 10" tabs.

Comment: In Android, "deprecated" means "we have another solution that we recommend you take a look at", not necessarily "using the deprecated solution is bad". `-swNNNdp` is only available on API Level 13, and there are some tablets (and lots of phones) running older versions of Android, where you have no choice but to use the original size buckets. Hence, it is fine to use `-large` and `-xlarge`, while Android 2.x is still significant, if you are shipping to devices running Android 3.1 or older.